# Missing = inserted for \ifnum

Tags: packages

I am trying to execute my code:

```
\documentclass[MACS,english]{gucthesis}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % For utf8 encoded .tex files allows norwegian characters in the files. This can be dangerous if you change to a differnt editor.
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{graphicx}  % For cross references in pdf
\usepackage{color}              % For colouring text   
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\input{MastersThesisData} % this is the file which contains all the details about your thesis
\makefrontpages % make the frontpages
\input{MastersIntro}


\tableofcontents

% Comment with a percent to remove figures or tables:
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\include{introduction} % includes latex files from the same directory
\include{packages} % could be called Methodology or methods or anyfile name 
\include{structure} % could be results
\include{GRIPPERS}
\include{INTEGRATION}
\include{Conclusion}



\bibliographystyle{gucthesis}
\bibliography{MastersExample}

\appendix
\include{appendix}

\end{document}
```

But I am getting two errors:

1. `Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \usepackage`
2. `Missing number, treated as zero. \usepackage`

can anyone please help me out with this.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you give a pointer for the `gucthesis` class?

Comment: Can we have copy-pasted text of the errors you get when you run the code you've posted, too? Error messages contain information about where the error is to be found e.g. line numbers etc. And you need to make your example so we can compile it. Even given the class file, we cannot do that right now because of all the `\input` and `\include` files.

Comment: hyperref generally likes to go last.  I'm not sure about inputenc.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. It was caused due to a missing `year` field in on of the BibTeX entries. I was able to fix the issue by adding the year field like this:
```
@online{arXiv,
    title = {arXiv.org e-Print archive},
    url = {https://arxiv.org/},
    author = {arXiv},
    year= {2023},
    urldate = {2023-08-07}
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I was getting this same error. I had a *.cls file which had an option as shown:

```
\ProvidesClass{classname}[notes]
```

Removing the "`[notes]`" fixed the problem. Minimal working example (both files are in the same directory):

classname.cls

```
\ProvidesClass{classname}[notes]
\LoadClass{report}
```

texname.tex

```
\documentclass{classname}
\begin{document}
  test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide the community with a custom class and an accompanying minimal example that replicates this?

Comment: Just added, Werner.

Comment: Starting the notes with a date, as in `\ProvidesClass{classname}[2017/02/27 notes]`, also fixes things for me.

Comment: This saved me, thank you!