# custom book class \ProvidesClass command

Tags: xetex

I am making a customized `book` class. The code below compiles successfully for a customized `article` class, but not with the `book` class [*EDIT*: no, actually, it fails both classes, for reasons explained by David Carlisle in his answer]. The problem appears to be in the `\ProvidesClass` command: it fails when I append a description to it inside the square brackets, but compiles once I comment it out. Any idea what is causing the problem, and what would be the proper way to handle this?

Comment out the bit `%[2016-04-20 v1.0 French LaTeX book class]` and the MWE will compile.

The main `french-book-main.tex` file, to be compiled:

```
% french-book-main.tex 
\documentclass[12pt]{french-book-template}
\begin{document}
\author{me}
\title{Test this custom book class document}
\maketitle
\chapter{First things first}
blablabla
\end{document}
```

for the `french-book-template.cls` class:

```
% french-book-template.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{french-book-template} %[2016-04-20 v1.0 French LaTeX book class]
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}% works with article class
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[openany,french]{book}% works with article class

%%  fonts and special characters
\RequirePackage{ifxetex} % load different packages with/without XeLaTex
\ifxetex
  \RequirePackage{fontspec}
\else  % not needed with utf8 based engines
  \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \RequirePackage{lmodern}
\fi%
\RequirePackage[french]{babel}
\RequirePackage[babel]{csquotes}
\endinput
```

I am compiling with `XeLaTex` in order to handle French and other foreign characters. The code is nearly minimal: I have added a few French bits for completeness (if anyone believes there is a better combination of packages/options, feel free to chime in). I'm using an up to date 2015 version of `TeXLive`.

The idea of commenting out the option in brackets came from [Missing = inserted for \ifnum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274650/missing-inserted-for-ifnum)

The basics of creating a custom book class came from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702222/can-i-write-cls-files-in-latex-instead-of-tex

Comment: Date strings of the form yyyy-mm-dd are allowed since LaTeX release as of April 2017.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Since the 2017 LaTeX Release LaTeX has accepted both forms 2020-04-04 and 2020/04/04 in almost all contexts where it looks for a date argument.

**Original Answer**
LaTeX date strings have to be in the form  `2016/04/20`  not `2016-04-20`

Comment: I see, thank you David: I was under the impression that you could write anything between the square brackets - I was wrong!  P.S. For some weird reason, I had the date written up properly in my `article` example and incorrectly in my `book` example. My eyes hadn't spotted the difference.

Comment: @PatrickT it is free form text except for the part before the first space which has to be yyyy/mm/dd as it is used to check the version if the user uses `\documentclass{yourclass}[2025/12/25]` (which essentially no one ever does:-)